# how to store a list of items in Gel Script

Tags: list, arraylist, jelly, clarity

I would like to create a process in Clarity 13.1 which sends an email to all managers belonging to different OBS units in IT Department containing the list of resources who did not complete their timesheet + the related time periods. (I did not copy all the codes here, sorry if it is still too long)

First, I wrote a query to select all the managers that I needed and the result is stored in var= "result3".

Then I wrote this:

```
<core:forEach items="${result3.rowsByIndex}" trim="true" var="mng">
 <core:set value="${mng[0]}" var="userid"/> 
<core:set value="${mng[1]}" var="ManagerLastName"/>
 <core:set value="${mng[2]}" var="ManagerFirstName"/>
 <core:set value="${mng[3]}" var="ManagerEmail"/>
 <core:set value="${mng[4]}" var="idManager"/>
 <gel:log> manager ${mng[1]} </gel:log>
```

Next I selected all the resources who did not compile their timesheet and the result is stored in result2.
and this is the last part:

```
<core:forEach items="${result2.rowsByIndex}" trim="true" var="tms">
 <core:set value="${tms[0]}" var="id_risorse"/>
 <core:set value="${tms[1]}" var="Full_Name"/>
 <core:set value="${tms[2]}" var="Email"/>
 <core:set value="${tms[3]}" var="Time_Period"/>
 <core:set value="${tms[4]}" var="Prid"/>
 <core:set value="${tms[5]}" var="MANAGER_ID"/>

<gel:log> Risorsa: ${tms[1]} periodo: "${tms[3]}"</gel:log> 

<gel:email from="clarity@mediobanca.it"
 subject="MISSING TIMESHEET: ${tms[3]}"
 to="${mng[3]}">

 ( Here is the CONTENT OF EMAIL
 Resource: ${tms[1]}, id= "${tms[0]}" 

 </gel:email> 

</core:forEach> 
</core:forEach> 
</core:forEach> 
</gel:script>
```

Here, the problem is that in this way, each manager receives lot of email related to each resource or each time period, while each manager must receive ONLY 1 email containing the LIST OF RESOURCES ...

I tried also putting the last two  after

I do appreciate if someone knows if it is possible to refer to the list of resources inside gel:email and how? or if I could write a loop inside a gel:email.

any answer or idea is highly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Mona

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier way to do this would be to group by the manager in the first query and create a field of concatenated resources (comma separated or LFCR separated or HTML 
 separated) without timesheets submitted.  This would give you just one query to loop through with the manager and resources for each manager.

As far as printing out the list inside the email, you may be able to use a forEach inside the email tag to iterate the list of non-compliant resources though I haven't tested this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may use aggregate function wm_concat or analytic function LISTAGG in your result2 query.

Ps. Assuming oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

My preference for scripts such as this is to use a single query to get all the data you need. Normally if you are doing timesheet escalation, you would only want to send the email to a resource's line manager or an individual in one part of the OBS. Hence the columns returned by your query could be: line manager (first name, last name & email address, resource id, resource full name, OBS path (plus any other things you need).

Your SQL should be grouped and ordered by line manager.

Have attributes previous line manager and current line manager. For each row returned where current=previous build up additional rows in an attribute called $resource_list.

When current <> previous then embed $resource_list into your email text and then send it. Note that you need to do a send for the final group too.

Best practice would be to format your emails as html and then use formatting to control how the missing timesheet resources are displayed.

I would only recommend that as an escalation. I would recommend send the resource a list of timesheets that they have not completed beforehand to give them a chance to sort out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand all managers will receive the same list of resources, then you can:

1. SQL Query to obtain the resource list with a missing timesheet
2. Fill the results in a GEL Variable
   ejm

```html
<core:forEach items="${result_resources.rows}" trim="true" var="myrow">    
<core:set var="var_string_results">${var_string_results} ${myrow.id_risorse} ${myrow.Full_Name},</core:set>         
</core:forEach>
```

3. Sql Query Managers
4. Use a GEL forEach with Manager array containing the gel:email tag

   ejm.

```html
<core:forEach begin="0" items="${vDestinatarios.rows}" var="slRow">        
 <core:set value="${slRow.email}" var="managers"/>   
 <gel:email from="clarity@mediobanca.it" fromName="clarity@mediobanca.it" subject="MISSING TIMESHEET" to="${managers}">
 <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
 <HTML> <HEAD/> 
 <BODY>
 ${var_string_results}       
 <![CDATA[ </BODY> </HTML> ]]>   
 </gel:email>
</core:forEach>
```

I hope it helps, and sorry if the above format is not the correct (it is my 1st answer)